# Can I use apollo federation just to modularize schema on same server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I want to define different schemas in different files and use them as one. The goal is to modularize schema. I've checked some of the apollo federation examples, all of them use schemas running on different servers. But there will be only one server in my case.

Comment: Hey I have written a simple library that could help you out, https://www.npmjs.com/package/idio-graphql

Comment: The library is awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but federation adds complexity and overhead that is completely unnecessary in this case. Use type extensions if you want to easily split up your schema, or utilize an existing library like `graphql-modules`.